# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable (Error)

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write the running time of a Python script to a `csv` file. But I am getting an error. How do I fix it?

```
with open('Time.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    print("Time (seconds) =",(time.time() - start_time))
    writer.writerows(time.time() - start_time)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    writer.writerows(time.time() - start_time)

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The argument to `writerows()` should be a list of rows. Each row should be a list of columns. You gave a single number. How do you expect that to work as a CSV?

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is "writer.writerow()" (without the s). Writerows requires an iterable object (such as an array of rows) writerow requires a single value.